# Guest User Cannot Send VF Email Template While Having Access to Object's Fields

Tags: workflow, email-template, permissions, email-alert, guest-user

I have a guest profile triggering a workflow rule/email alert when they click "Save Information" button on a public portal. If I log in as myself (internal user) the flow works and I get the email, but when I try and run it as a guest, I get an error of "Submission Error: The record couldn't be saved because it triggered an email alert that failed. Please contact salesforce.com Customer Support."

I gave this guest profile that will be triggering this workflow rule/email alert System Permissions to send emails, but still get this error. Is there anything else on the backend that  I have to enable for this guest user to be able to trigger my workflow rule/email alert?

P.S. The guest profile has access to all Apex Controllers, Object fields, etc. related to this public portal.

Update: email template that is being triggered in this email alert is a visual force email template that is calling on a the object we are using to prepopulate a pdf form being sent out (<messaging:emailTemplate ... relatedTo=Application__c>). I replaced the email template on the email alert from the vf pages email template to a plain text on and it worked. Both the VF Email Template and the Plaintext Email Template are in the same Folder so I know its not a Folder access issue. The guest profile has read/edit access to every field on the Application object though so I do not know why the guest user is still running into issues.

Comment: Does the Guest user also has access to this VF page? Can you please try by adding this VF page in Sites available pages?

Comment: I had to add `renderUsingSystemContextWithoutSharing="true"` at the top of my VF email template since the user profile was a Guest.